# Delphi How to retrieve all parameters as single string

Tags: delphi, parameters

application1 runs another application2 with 2 parameters eg:
(NOTE: application1 is not my program)

```
application2.exe -d:C:\Program Files\app folder -z:Folder menu\app icons
```

Problem is... quotes somehow disappeared so instead of 2 parameters application2 will get 5 parameters

```
Param1=-d:C:\Program
Param2=Files\app
Param3=folder
Param4=-z:Folder menu\app
Param5=app icons
```

Is there way to retrieve all parameters as single string?

I tried combine parameters in loop

```
for i:=1 to ParamCount do
parameters=parameters+' '+ParamStr(i);
```

but it is not good solution, because path can contain also double or triple spaces 
eg.

```
Program files\app   folder\
```

cmd.exe can capture all parameters in %* , but it gives wrong results if parameter contains special characters like ^^~@@&& ...

Comment: Gentlemen, you are proposing rather clumsy solution because command line is already initialized by RTL to `System.CmdLine` variable. Cross-platform behavior isn't implemented tho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call the Windows API function [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) to retrieve the original command line.

```
var
  CmdLine: string;
....
CmdLine := GetCommandLine;
```

You'd better hope that you never need to work with a file whose name contains a dash following a space! Trying to persuade the author of the other application to fix their programming would be prudent.

Answer (score 7):

If you are ending up with 5 parameters instead of 2, it is because application1 DID NOT quote the parameters to begin with, eg:

```
application2.exe "-d:C:\Program Files\app folder" "-z:Folder menu\app icons"
```

Or:

```
application2.exe -d:"C:\Program Files\app folder" -z:"Folder menu\app icons"
```

Assuming you cannot get the author of application1 to fix the parameters, you will have to use [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the original command line and parse it yourself however you need.  Just keep in mind that unless ALL of your parameters start with `-`, or unless the parameters are quoted, then you are likely going to run into issues parsing spaces.  That is what quotation marks are meant to handle.